# Is there a web front-end that allows for easily deployment of apps/files directly from SVN?

Tags: svn, deployment, export

I have some scripts in SVN that are managed by a few people.  Every few weeks, once everyone's changes are in, I tag a revision and then deploy that tag to an Ubuntu server (a very simple svn export on the ubuntu server).  I'd like to make it easy for other people to manage these deployments by providing a simple web front-end that will allow a user to select the appropriate tag, select a target directory and then export the tag to that directory.  Does something like this already exist?  If not, has anyone built a process similar to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple good SaaS solutions: [Springloops](http://www.springloops.com/v2/) and [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)

Seems like you could do it fairly easily with a simple HTML form and a script (PHP, Python, etc.).

Comment: A python app is my fallback, but the team doesn't really have the bandwidth to write and maintain it right now.